# Getting Attribute Value in a class without using Access beans

Tags: java, ejb, websphere-commerce

I wanted to get the value of an assigned attribute of a product into a java class without using Access beans. Is there any way to get the value?

Comment: @BalusC Oh now it makes sense... Thank you.

Comment: I'm curious. Any particular reason for wanting to avoid the AccessBeans?

Answer (score 0):

Look at extending the BaseJDBCHelper class and getting it out of the attrval table with sql.